# why function are not getting executed in sequence?

Tags: java, android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the problem...I have three different functions namely `syncFirebaseContacts(); getAllContacts(); and compareContactUpdateList();`. These function's execution order is very important because first function's output becomes input of another. As I have said I have placed these three function in my `onCreate()` method in sequence as described.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        datasource = new AdoreDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        syncFirebaseContacts(); 
        getAllContacts();
        compareContactUpdateList();
       .......
```

But while debugging I found out that **although pointer points `syncFirebaseContacts()`** first but the code of `getAllContact()` is executed  first and then `compareContactUpdateList()` is executed and after that `syncFirebaseContacts()` code is executed.

```
private void getAllContacts() {
    String contactNumber;
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    //All Mapping Stuff to be done here..
                    contactNumber = contactNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    contactNumber = contactNumber.trim();
                    lst2.add(contactNumber);
                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}


private void syncFirebaseContacts() {
    Firebase userLocationRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USERS);
    userLocationRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                datasource.createContact(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey()));
                lst1.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getKey()));
                Log.e("Hello", String.valueOf(dsp.getKey()));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.e("Could not process", "Sorry");
        }
    });

}


private void compareContactsUpdateList() {
    ArrayList<String> commonOfAll = new ArrayList<String>(lst1);
    commonOfAll.retainAll(lst2);
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    final ArrayList<ContactsList> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactsList>();
    //List<SyncContacts> syncContacts = datasource.getAllContacts();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String nameOfContact = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contactNumber = contactNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    contactNumber = contactNumber.trim();
                    Log.d("Name ", nameOfContact + contactNumber);
                    for(int j =0; j < commonOfAll.size(); j++){
                        if(contactNumber.equals(commonOfAll)){
                            Log.d("Name ", nameOfContact);
                            contacts.add(new ContactsList(contactNumber, nameOfContact, R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    final ContactsAdapterTwo contactsAdapterTwo = new ContactsAdapterTwo(this, contacts);
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);

    gridView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gridView.setAdapter(contactsAdapterTwo);
        }
    });

}
```

As my problem is that I want to compare two lists which is done in `compareContactsUpdateList()`  by the line 
    `ArrayList<String> commonOfAll = new ArrayList<String>(lst1);
    commonOfAll.retainAll(lst2);` as I found out that `lst1` is always empty because `syncFirebaseContacts() 's` code is excuted at last

My applogies if my question length is too long or if my problem is trivial. But it is a big problem for me coz I am new to coding :-) please help me....Anyways Thanx in advance...

Comment: How are you debugging ?

Comment: thank u for replying @javaguy ... i am debugging using default Android Studio's debug tool

Comment: Firebase works asynchronously by default. You cannot expect to have an async method returned the way you are doing it. I suggest you implement a callback and perform `getAllContacts();` and `compareContactUpdateList();` once Firebase has fetched your data

Comment: any example please....how to implement callback...

Comment: you can google that and I'm sure you'll find lots of examples

Comment: okay thanx....brother